# How can I disable a button in my todo list using hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to figure out how I would be able to disable the  button in my todo-listitems after pressing one, so it allows to only update/edit one listitem at once, but I cant seem to find a solution for that. I know I need another hook for it, however I dont know how to implement it though. (The currentEdit is the useState hook I want to use)
This is my code so far:

Main.jsx:

```
    const Main = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [currentEdit, setcurrentEdit] = useState(false);

  const handleAdd = (input) => {
    const newTodo = {
      text: input,
      id: todos.length + 1, //Hier .length +1
      date: Date.now(),
      isEdit: false,
      isComplete: false,
    };
    //..todos - all "previous todos" , todo - new todo
    const newTodos = [newTodo, ...todos];
    console.log(newTodos);
    setTodos(newTodos);
  };

  // is todo being edited?
  const editTodo = (id) => {
    let editTodos = todos.map((todo) => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.isEdit = !todo.isEdit;
      }
      return todo;
    });
    setTodos(editTodos);
  };

  //Update a todo
  const handleUpdate = (id, newText) => {
    let newTodos = todos.map((todo) => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.text = newText;
      }
      return todo;
    });
    setTodos(newTodos);
  };

  //delete a todo from list
  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    const deleteArr = [...todos].filter((todo) => todo.id !== id);
    setTodos(deleteArr);
  };

  //mark the todo as completed (toggle)
  const completeTodo = (id) => {
    let updatedTodos = todos.map((todo) => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.isComplete = !todo.isComplete;
      }
      return todo;
    });
    setTodos(updatedTodos);
  };

  //delete all completed tasks
  const deleteFinished = () => {
    const finishedArr = [...todos].filter((todo) => !todo.isComplete);
    setTodos(finishedArr);
  };

  //SORTING BY TYPE
  const sortTodo = (type) => (a, b) => {
    const A = a[type];
    const B = b[type];

    let compare = 0;
    if (A > B) {
      compare = 1;
    } else if (A < B) {
      compare = -1;
    }
    return compare;
  };

  return (
    <div className='todo-wrapper'>
      <div className='dots'></div>
      <h1 className='text-550 leading-tight md:text-650'>What needs to be done today?</h1>

      <Form todos={todos} onSubmit={handleAdd} />
      <List
        todos={todos}
        completeTodo={completeTodo}
        handleDelete={handleDelete}
        handleUpdate={handleUpdate}
        editTodo={editTodo}
      />

      <div className='btn-container'>
        <button
          className='text-400 md:text-450 pd-200 br-s color-dark reset-btn'
          onClick={() => setTodos([...todos].sort(sortTodo('text')))}
        >
          {' '}
          A - Z <ImArrowDown />
        </button>
        <button
          className='text-400 md:text-450 pd-200 br-s color-dark reset-btn'
          onClick={() => setTodos([...todos].sort(sortTodo('id')).reverse())}
        >
          Date <ImArrowDown />
        </button>
        <button
          className='text-400 md:text-450 pd-200 br-s color-dark  reset-btn'
          onClick={deleteFinished}
        >
          Delete Finished
        </button>
        <button
          className='text-400 md:text-450 pd-200 br-s color-dark reset-btn'
          onClick={handleReset}
        >
          <FaRegTrashAlt /> Delete All!
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

Form.jsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const Form = (props) => {
  //Declare Hook for Input
  const [input, setInput] = useState(props.isEdit ? props.todo.text : '');

  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  });

  // Function for Submitting Todos

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!input || /^\s*$/.test(input)) {
      return;
    }
    props.onSubmit(input);
    setInput('');
  };

  return (
    <section id='todo-form' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <form action=''>
        <input
          type='text'
          name='text'
          id=''
          placeholder="What's on your plate.."
          onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
          value={input}
          className={`text-400 md:text-450 color-dark ${
            props.isEdit ? 'input-edit' : ''
          }`}
          ref={inputRef}
        />
        <button
          className={`text-400 md:text-450 color-dark todo-btn ${
            props.isEdit ? 'bg-secondary edit' : 'bg-primary'
          }`}
        >
          {props.isEdit ? 'Update' : 'Add'}
        </button>
      </form>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

List.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ListItem from './ListItem';

const List = ({ todos, editTodo, completeTodo, handleDelete, handleUpdate }) => {
  return (
    <section id='todo-list'>
      <ul className='list'>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <ListItem
            key={todo.id}
            todo={todo}
            completeTodo={completeTodo}
            handleDelete={handleDelete}
            handleUpdate={handleUpdate}
            editTodo={editTodo}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
};

export default List;
```

And Listitem.jsx:

```
import { FaRegTrashAlt } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { FiEdit } from 'react-icons/fi';
import React from 'react';
import Form from './Form';

const ListItem = ({
  todo,
  todo: { isComplete, isEdit, text, id },
  handleUpdate,
  handleDelete,
  editTodo,
  completeTodo,
}) => {
  const klick = (todoText) => {
    handleUpdate(id, todoText);
    editTodo(id);
  };

  if (isEdit) {
    return <Form todo={todo} isEdit={isEdit} onSubmit={klick} />;
  }

  return (
    <li className={'pd-200 list__item ' + (isComplete ? 'complete' : '')}>
      <button
        className='text-400 md:text-450 list__item--second'
        onClick={() => completeTodo(id)} //CompleteTodo
      >
        <span>
          {text}
          <svg
            preserveAspectRatio='none'
            vectorEffect='non-scaling-stroke'
            viewBox='0 0 154 30'
            fill='none'
            xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
          >
            <path
              className='strike'
              d='M5 7c46.8-.5 141.1-3.7 141.5 1.5.4 5.2-97.3 6.8-144.5 9.5l150.5 5'
              stroke='#5B2929'
              strokeWidth='2'
              strokeLinecap='round'
              strokeLinejoin='round'
            />
          </svg>
        </span>
      </button>
      <div className='icons'>
        {!isComplete && (
          <button
            onClick={() => editTodo(id)}
            //   setEdit({ id: id, value: text, date: date })

            //   console.log(id)

            className='text-400 md:text-450 edit-btn'
          >
            <FiEdit />
          </button>
        )}
        <button
          onClick={() => handleDelete(id)} //handleDelete
          className='text-400 md:text-450 delete-btn'
        >
          <FaRegTrashAlt />
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};

export default ListItem;
```